# Training Data Format with Spacy

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, spacy

I am trying to build NLP with Spacy, but I am having trouble formatting the training data. I want my app to be able to recognize entities and intents. For example, in "I want to place an order for pizza". The intent would be "place_order" and the entity would be pizza. How do I format the training data for BOTH entities and intents in Spacy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you cast the problem as NLP challenges. You could try to recognize entities like "pizza" with a Named Entity Recognizer, but beware that this model is designed mainly for truely **named** entities - i.e. entities with a name that refer to a unique entity in the real world, like London or Google.

Nevertheless, we've seen use-cases where the NER model works reasonably well for non-named entities. You can follow the training guide [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-train-ner) and format your data like so:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]
```

Another potential approach for this "pizza" entity are rule-based matching / dictionary lookup, depending how large a variety you expect. You can find more about rule-based matching strategies in spaCy [here](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching). Note that this approach wouldn't require training data, but you'd need to carefully craft the rules.

For "intent", again you have a few options. Either cast it as an NER challenge to find the verb phrase "place an order", but with the same caveat that this is not a real named entity. Perhaps a better approach would be to see this as a text classification challenge, and predict the "intent" label for the whole sentence. You can find the documentation on text classification [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#textcat), and the data format would need to be a dictionary with each potential label getting a `1.0` or a `0.0`:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("I'm so happy.", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 1.0, "NEGATIVE": 0.0}}),
    ("I'm so angry", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 0.0, "NEGATIVE": 1.0}}),
]
```

Finally, a more complex approach is to use the dependency parser for your intent classification, cf the code example [here](https://spacy.io/usage/examples#intent-parser). While this seems more difficult to get started with, and to annotate data for, it could also be the most powerful option.

Comment: Thank you. I also want entities. I want BOTH intents and entities.

Comment: You'll probably want to train two separate classifiers on these two problems. For each problem, I've outlined several potential solutions.